# NetSuite Integration | REST API | SalesOrder Fulfillment process issues

Tags: javascript

I've built an Integration between my system to NetSutie using REST API.
Now I'm trying to fulfill an order that is currently pending fulfillment and I get the following error no matter what I try.

```
{
    "type": "https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#section-15.5.1",
    "title": "Bad Request",
    "status": 400,
    "o:errorDetails": [
        {
            "detail": "Error while accessing a resource. You must have at least one valid line item for this transaction.",
            "o:errorCode": "USER_ERROR"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I double checked all the details inside the Paylaod I send.

```
{
    "subsidiary": {
        "id": "6"
    },
    "createdFrom": {
        "id": "10478564" //NetSuite Order Internal ID
    },
    "package": {
        "items": [
            {
                "packageTrackingNumber": "6546545646546", //Random Tracking Number
                "packageWeight": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    "shipStatus": {
        "id": "C",
        "refName": "Shipped"
    },
    "item": {
        "items": [
            {
                "orderLine": 1, //Order Line Item
                "quantity": 1,
                "location": {
                    "id": "1" //NetSuite Location ID
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Their documantation is so Bad.

I have tried that: https://.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/salesOrder//!transform/itemFulfillment

Payload:

```
{
    "subsidiary": {
        "id": "6"
    },
    "createdFrom": {
        "id": "10478564" //NetSuite Order Internal ID
    },
    "package": {
        "items": [
            {
                "packageTrackingNumber": "6546545646546", //Random Tracking Number
                "packageWeight": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    "shipStatus": {
        "id": "C",
        "refName": "Shipped"
    },
    "item": {
        "items": [
            {
                "orderLine": 1, //Order Line Item
                "quantity": 1,
                "location": {
                    "id": "1" //NetSuite Location ID
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Also Tried that:
POST https://<accountID>/services/rest/record/v1/salesorder/{{SALES_ORDER_ID}}/!transform/itemFulfillment
{
    "item":{
       "items":[
          {
            "orderLine":1,
            "location":6,
            "itemreceive": true
          }
          {
            "orderLine": 3
            "location": 6,
            "itemreceive": false
          }
       ]
    }
} 



https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_161425629582.html#subsect_161425663087